# Add and remove class when element clicked with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I would like to know how to add or remove a class to an HTML element when a div is clicked with AngularJS. I have a div that when clicked I need to check if it includes a class('already-member') or not. If the class exist, then remove it, and if it does not, then add it. I know how to do this in Javascript but not sure in Angular.

tab-members.html

```
<div collection-repeat="friend in user.friends" item-width="50%" item-height="80px" class="friends-list">
  <div class="item friend-avatar" ng-class="{'already-member' : friend.already_member == true}" ng-click="toggleStatus()">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="{{friend.avatar_url}}">
      <i class="check-icon" ng-class="{'hidden' : friend.already_member == false}"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-friend-name">
      <p class="friend-name">{{friend.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the code in controllers.js

```
.controller('MembersCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.members = [
    {avatar_url: "http://..."},
    {avatar_url: "http://..."},
    {avatar_url: "http://..."},
    {avatar_url: "http://..."}
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    avatar_url: "http://...",
    friends: [
      {avatar_url: "http://...", name: "Pablo Pepunto", already_member: true},
      {avatar_url: "http://...", name: "Pablo Pepunto", already_member: false},
      {avatar_url: "http://...", name: "Pablo Pepunto", already_member: false},
      {avatar_url: "http://...", name: "Pablo Pepunto", already_member: false}
    ]
  }
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
    viewData.enableBack = true;
  });
  $scope.toggleStatus = function($scope) {
    console.log('$scope'); //$scope is undefined
    $scope.classList.toggle('already_member');
    $scope.already_member = !$scope.already_member;

  }
})
```

Comment: On a side note, you should use === instead of ==. Shallow equals can sometimes lead to unintended results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

In the template:

```
ng-click="toggleStatus(friend)"
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.toggleStatus = function(friend) {
    friend.already_member = !friend.already_member;
}
```

Then the `ng-class="{'hidden' : friend.already_member == false}"` directive you defined should work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a ng-click Listener on your div element. When the click is triggered, toggle a boolean variable `isMember` in your controller to set the class.
2. Use the ng-class directive with your isMember variable on your div to check whether `isMember` is set or not: `ng-class="{'already-member': isMember}"`

You could also set and use the variable directly like this:

```
<div ng-click="isMember = !isMember" ng-class="{'already-member': isMember}">
```

I recommend setting the flag in your controller for better readability.

Comment: With this solution I would have to define isMember in the controller to true or false. But I can't set it that way beacuse it depends from the Boolean of friend.already_member

Comment: The replace isMember by friend.already_member. It does not matter how you name your variables

Comment: ok. It has worked it by replacing friend.already_member for isMember. Thanks for your help